# Which one is better: multivariate regression with basis expansion or neural networks?

Tags: neural-networks, comparison, regression

Assume we are given a training dataset $D = \{ (x_i, y_i)\}_{i=1}^{N}$.

My question is: which is better?

1. A multivariate regression with basis expansion with *independent matrix* $X$ and *dependent matrix* $Y$, such that $X \in K; K \subset \mathbb R^n$ and $Y \in \mathbb R^m$ with training data $D$.

*Or*

2. A neural network which takes $n$ *input variables* and returns $m$ *output* with training data $D$

> Without a doubt, the multivariate regression option is better with its basis polynomials because it can adapt any curve required in any dimension and doesn't need a large number of datasets than neural networks. Then, why neural networks are used more than multivariate regression?

**Note: Prefer explaining the mechanism of neural network used as regression in your answers. To help us know the degree of flexibility of both.**

**Edit: You may prefer choosing your own loss function in case you need.**

Comment: This question is impossible to answer. There is no objective 'better' solution unless you know more about the shape of the data. It's like asking "what's better, a fork or a spoon?" -- depends on whether you want to eat soup or steak.

Comment: @OliverMason You may explain in which case which is better.